# PowerBI measure dynamic average per multiple categories

Tags: powerbi, dax

The following measure shows the average per Werks and MATNR but static, for all values in the table.

```
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX(
        SUMMARIZE( LieferscheineUnique, LieferscheineUnique[WERKS], LieferscheineUnique[MATNR] ),
        CALCULATE( AVERAGE(LieferscheineUnique[fci_zu_PA] ) )
    ),
    ALLEXCEPT(  LieferscheineUnique, LieferscheineUnique[WERKS], LieferscheineUnique[MATNR] )
)
```

I have the following table

| DATUM | WERKS | ID | MATNR | fci_zu_PA | Average_fci_per_Werks&MATNR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08.04.2021 | H006 | 1 | 10009 | 41,7 | 35,84 |
| 12.04.2021 | H006 | 2 | 10009 | 43,3 | 35,84 |
| 14.04.2021 | H006 | 3 | 10009 | 43,5 | 35,84 |
| 08.04.2021 | H100 | 4 | 10009 | 43,3 | 38,20 |
| 22.04.2021 | H100 | 5 | 10009 | 43,3 | 38,20 |
| 22.04.2021 | H100 | 6 | 10010 | 24,5 | 35,01 |

Now I want the average per WERKS and MATNR displayed in each row according to the date filter.

The desired output would look like this:

| DATUM | WERKS | ID | MATNR | fci_zu_PA | Average_fci_per_Werks&MATNR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08.04.2021 | H006 | 1 | 10009 | 41,7 | 42,83 |
| 12.04.2021 | H006 | 2 | 10009 | 43,3 | 42,83 |
| 14.04.2021 | H006 | 3 | 10009 | 43,5 | 42,83 |
| 08.04.2021 | H100 | 4 | 10009 | 43,7 | 43,50 |
| 22.04.2021 | H100 | 5 | 10009 | 43,3 | 43,50 |
| 22.04.2021 | H100 | 6 | 10010 | 24,5 | 24,50 |

It would be great if someone knows how to achieve this.